# Bash script loop issue when replacing constant by variable

Tags: bash, loops

A standard loop works fine for me

```
for i in {1..3}
do
    echo "$i" 
done
```

Output

```
1
2
3
```

But if I replace the constant by a variable (after declaring it, of course) it doesn't.

```
n=3
for i in {1..$n}
do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Output

```
{1..3}
```

Apologies if it's a dumb question. I tried to search on SO and Google but not luck.

Follow up question:

```
declare -a nOptions={3,4};
for i1 in $(seq 1 ${nOptions[0]});
do
  for i2 in $(seq 1 ${nOptions[1]});
  do
    echo "$i1$i2"
  done
done
```

This gives output

```
11
21 
31
41
```

and not

```
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
31
32
33
34
```

as expected.

Comment: This is a FAQ, by the way. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D

Comment: Your `nOptions` isn't a valid array declaration. Maybe you mean `nOptions=( 3 4 )`?

Comment: You need to declare `nOptions` as an array, which means parentheses on the right hand side.  You can still use curly braces inside the parentheses if you want to make a sequence:  `nOptions=({3..5})`

Answer (score 3):

Curly-brace expansion takes place before parameter expansion (or any other expansion). The literal `$variable` doesn't look like the other end of a range, so it doesn't trigger the range expansion.

To use a variable count, just use a counting loop:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$n; ++i )); do 

done
```

On most modern systems (at least Linux and OS X) you can use the `seq` command, although it's neither part of the POSIX standard nor built-in to Bash itself:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $n); do

done
```

If you were for some reason dead-set on using curlies, you could add an `eval`, but that will make the solution fragile and dangerous.

Comment: thanks mark! a follow up questions (which was my original question before i edited it). when applying this for nested loop, it only works for the outermost variable, but not others :( any suggestions?

Comment: Boo, hiss re: `seq` -- not part of the POSIX standard, and also not a bash builtin, so no guarantee it'll be present on any given system even if that system does have bash. Much better to use the C-style loop -- or, if one wants POSIX compatibility, `i=0; while [ "$i" -lt "$n" ]; do ...; i=$((i + 1)); done`